# Падежи количественных числительных

Tags: грамотная-речь

Привожу отрывок из научного текста на русском сайте: "К примеру, Леонардо да Винчи было достаточно всего 1,5-2 часа сна в день, Николе Тесла — 2-3 часа". Не думайте ли вы, что правильно было бы, если бы вместо формы "1,5-2 часа сна в день, Николе Тесла 2-3 часа" стояла форма "1,5-2 часов сна в день, Николе Тесла 2-3 часов", ввиду того, что эта количественная группа управляется словом "достаточно"?

Comment: Теймураз, Вы в очередной раз беседу на русском, междусобойчик, называете научным текстом или научным сайтом! Они ж не по языковым проблемам научные, не стоит на них ориентироваться.

Answer (score 1):

Перво-наперво. У *Николы Теслы* фамилия склоняется: ***Николе Тесле***.

Что касается сути вопроса... Настолько витиевато сформулирован, что остается только догадываться.

Если вопрос об управлении словом "достаточно", то да, правильное общелитературное употребление требует родительного падежа. ***"Достаточно полутора-двух часов"***.

Надо признать, однако, что в научной литературе родительный падеж активно заменяется винительным (для мужского и среднего рода). Причины могут быть разные: 1) смешение с ***"достаточны два часа"***, 2) уподобление слову "требуется": ***"требуется полтора-два часа"***, 3) переосмысление как перечисление: ***"достаточно: два часа, то-то и то-то, это и это"***. 
Но, на мой взгляд, независимо от мотивировки эта ошибка грубая и не подлежащая какому-либо узаконению.